# How do I write a helper in rails to get First initial. Last Name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def formatted(format)
  case format

  when :readable_full
  [first_name, middle_initial, last_name].select(&:present?).join(" ").titleize

  when :readable_short
  [first_name, last_name].select(&:present?).join(" ").titleize

else
  fail InvalidFormatError
 end
end
```

`# :readable_full => Mike A Smith
 # :readable_short => Mike Smith`

Now I want to do something like this 
`# :readable_first_initial` => M. Smith

assuming something like this

```
   when :readable_first_initial
  [first_name, + ".", last_name].select(&:present?).join(" ").titleize
```

How do I get the first character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String#[]`.

```
str = "ABCD"
str[0] # => "A"
```

So following your preferred format, you can do:

```
[first_name[0], ".", last_name].select(&:present?).join(" ").titleize
```

**Edit:** As pointed out, this will add an extra space. If you prefer this format, you can do:

```
[first_name[0] + ".", last_name].select(&:present?).join(" ").titleize
```

Another option is to use string interpolation if you don't like using the `+`:

```
["#{first_name[0]}.", last_name].select(&:present?).join(" ").titleize
```

Comment: am getting  `M . Smith` can how do i get rid of the space between M and .

Comment: Maybe something like `["#{first_name[0]}.", last_name].select(&:present?).join(" ").titleize` would be an improvement? However, that would result in ". Smith" if first_name was blank.